# How to remove null value from distinct column of a table in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want only distint city from a table but that column contains null value i dont it to come in column when i do distinct city.

```
select distinct city from billingsystem
```

the output am getting is

```
newyork
london
dallas
null 
charles
```

I want output to be as

```
newyork 
london 
dallas
charles
```

can anybody help me out in doing this.

Comment: what's wrong with `where city is not null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below query

```
select distinct city from billingsystem  where city is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
select distinct city from billingsystem  where city is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

The given query is correct

The `Distinct` keyword it use to select the distinct values only, In where condition we where mentioned like IS NOT NULL condition so from here you can get the exact answer.

```
select distinct city 
from billingsystem  
where city is not null
```